# How to view home directory with Finder

Tags: macos, finder, folders

Brand new to Mac OS, coming from Linux.

Almost everything I do is out of my home dir ("`~/`", or on Mac, "`/Users/myuser/`"). But when I open up the Finder app, I can't figure out how to view  my home dir:

[image]

At first glance, it seems like my only options are `Desktop`, `Documents` or `Downloads`.

So I ask: **from this screen shot, how do I get to my home directory?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to open finder's preferences and check your username : 
[image: Finder]

You'll be able to find your home directory in finder next.

Comment: To add, in Finder preferences on the General tab, you can set new Finder windows to open your home directory (like when you click on the Finder icon in the Dock without any windows already open, or if you use cmd+n)

Answer (score 3):

Notwithstanding Hamsa'a answer [which is correct] you can add any location to that 'Favourites' list just by dragging it from the directories on the right into a gap the list on the left. [Dragging on top will move/copy to that location, hence, drop it between existing items.]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yet another option: whether or not you've added the home folder to the Finder sidebar, you can choose Home from the Finder's Go menu, or use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd>. The keyboard shortcut also works in the standard Open and Save dialogs.